# ExtJs Controller events

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, controller

How does controllers in ExtJs handle the events as shown below? If all button clicks go through the controller will it slow it down a lot?

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MyResults', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores : ['Store1', 'Store2'],
    models : ['MyModel'],
    views : ['myResults.Grid']
},

init: function() {
    this.control({
        'button': {
            click: this.refreshGrid
        }
    });
}
```

);

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you mean for your `init` method to be inside the controller definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will, and that is why the component selectors should be as specific as possible. In your case, assuming that `myResults.Grid` is defined as:

```
Ext.define('myResults.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel', // Not necessarily this class
    alias:  'widget.myresultsgrid', // xtype === 'myresultsgrid'
    ...
});
```

You can define your Controller as:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MyResults', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    ...
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'myresultsgrid button': {
                click: this.refreshGrid
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This will ensure that your Controller will see `click` events only from buttons in MyResults grid.

Comment: What will the difference between 'myresultsgrid > button' and just 'myresultsgrid button'?

Comment: @javaguy '>' operator will search for direct children, i.e. buttons that `myresultsgrid` contains as first level children. The 'myresultsgrid button' will look for any button that is contained by `myresultsgrid`, not necessarily a direct child. So if you place the buttons in a toolbar that is docked to the top of the grid, 'myresults button' will find them and your controller will get their events, but 'myresults > button' will not, because the buttons will not be direct children of the grid. See [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) documentation.